# How to join two series before draw graph in highstocks?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two javascript data arrays in the following format,

```
series one: [{date:20170220,price:25},{date:20170221,price:25},......{date:20170322,price:25},{date:20170323,price:55}]
series two: [{date:20170220,price:30},{date:20170221,price:28},......{date:20170322,price:24},{date:20170323,price:23}]
```

two values are {Date,price}.We cannot guarantee that data is available for a specific date in both series. And I want to create a third series that includes the `average` price for each day. Is there a way to get the third series in `highstocks`. Appreciate any javascript base solution.

Comment: What do you want for missing dates? either average or just keep as it is?

Comment: for missing dates, I want to keep `undefined` average value in the third series

Comment: And what is this `{20170220,25}` data structure? Not an object right?

Comment: it is an object. question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this snippet will address you through what you want.

Just looping through 2 arrays and creating third array. I left `price` key as undefined as your requirement.

```js
var s1 = [{date:20170220, price: 25},{date: 20170221, price: 25},{date: 20170322, price: 25},{date: 20170325,price: 55}];
var s2 = [{date: 20170220,price: 30},{date: 20170221,price: 28},{date: 20170323, price: 24},{date: 20170324, price: 23}];

var sortHelper = function(a, b){return a.date - b.date}

//sorting them for sanity
s1.sort(sortHelper);
s2.sort(sortHelper);
var s1Index = 0, s2Index = 0, s3 = [];
while(s1Index < s1.length || s2Index < s2.length){
  if(s1Index >= s1.length){ //for extreme conditions
    for(;s2Index < s2.length; s2Index++){
      s3.push({
        date: s2[s2Index].date
      });  
    }
    break;
  }
  if(s2Index >= s2.length){ //for extreme conditions
    for(;s1Index < s1.length; s1Index++){
      s3.push({
        date: s1[s1Index].date
      });  
    }
    break;
  }
  if(s1[s1Index].date === s2[s2Index].date){
    s3.push({
      date: s1[s1Index].date,
      price: (s1[s1Index].price + s2[s2Index].price) / 2
    });
    s1Index++;
    s2Index++;
  }else if(s1[s1Index].date < s2[s2Index].date){
    s3.push({
      date: s1[s1Index].date
    });
    s1Index++;
  }else if(s1[s1Index].date > s2[s2Index].date){
    s3.push({
      date: s2[s2Index].date
    });
    s2Index++;
  }
}

console.log(s3);
```